# Get email from HTML get XMLHTTP faster

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I have created a user-defined function for the purpose of getting an email from specific html like that

```
Sub Test()
Debug.Print GetEmailFromHTML("https://www.archaeology.lk/pharmacylocator/pharmacy_details.php?PhamercyID=589")
End Sub

Function GetEmailFromHTML(sURL As String)
Dim html As New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", sURL, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

On Error Resume Next
    GetEmailFromHTML = html.querySelectorAll("a[href*='mailto']")(0).innerText
On Error GoTo 0
Set html = Nothing
End Function
```

When running the Test macro, the code takes too much time but it works well at last. Is there a way to get XMLHTTP works faster or is there alternative approach to do so? All that I need from the URL is to get the email information.

Comment: Minimal improvement but you might as well just use querySelector so as to stop matching at first node. I can't view that page btw.  It is likely the speed problem is server side and outside your control.

Comment: Avoid auto-instantiation as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What do you mean with auto-instantiation ..? Do you mean this line `Dim html As New HTMLDocument`?

Comment: Yes. Instead Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip.